# How to scrape table between comments into grid view with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, gridview, web-scraping, datatable, html-agility-pack

Currently attempting to scrape the table from [this page](https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/stat/effective-field-goal-pct) into a gridview using the htmlagilitypack. I believe my code is successfully pulling the table from between the comments, but when it goes to build the data table it says it cant find column 8, which obviously shouldn't exist in this context. I'm somewhat new to this and would really appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong

```
private void GetTeamStats()
{
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var getPage = webGet.Load("https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/stat/effective-field-goal-pct");
    var commentNode = getPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()[contains(.,'table-filters')]/following::*[not(preceding::comment()[contains(.,'main-wrapper')])]");
    var commentHtml = commentNode.Select(c1 => c1.SelectSingleNode("//table"));

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Rk", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Team", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("2018", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Last3", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Last1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Home", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Away", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("2017", typeof(string));

    foreach (var table in commentHtml)
    {
        foreach (var row in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
        {
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
            {
                dr[i++] = cell.InnerText;
            }
        }

        gvTeamStats.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

The exception says "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find column 8.'" and is being thrown by this line of code

```
                    dr[i++] = cell.InnerText;
```

Comment: It's helpful if you describe which line is throwing the exception, and paste the actual exception message here. I see 8 columns being created.

Comment: the first column in the data table would be read as column 0 so there should be no column 8, just 0-7. I edited my question to include the exception and specify the line throwing it.

Comment: the problem is dr[i++] = cell.InnerText; is trying to add second row "2" to same dr. you arent adding the row to datatable and creating a new dr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes:

table structure in View source of page is:

```
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>2018</th>
    <th>Last 3</th>
    <th>Last 1</th>
    <th>Home</th>
    <th>Away</th>
    <th>2017</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var getPage = webGet.Load("https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/stat/effective-field-goal-pct");
var tableHeader = getPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/thead/tr");
var tableData = getPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr");

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

var headers = tableHeader
            .Elements("th")
            .Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim());

foreach (var header in headers)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add(header);
}

var rows = tableData.Select(tr => tr
            .Elements("td")
            .Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim())
            .ToArray());

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}

// print our datatable
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
     foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
     {
         Console.Write(item + " ");
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
 }
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the exception "System.ArgumentException: 'This row already belongs to this table.'" at the line "dataTable.Rows.Add(dr)" inside the else statement

Comment: This works when I assign the data source outside of the loops, but it seems to be cutting off the first column of data in the next row down. So instead of row 2 starting with the rank, it starts with the team name, row 3 starts with the first fg% etc. etc. Also, I really appreciate the help, been stuck on this forever.

Comment: Also this appears to infinitely build the table, so after 30, a new row would start at row 1, which explains why it was taking so long to debug.

Comment: Added an if statement that breaks the loop when the datatable has 30 rows, so i fixed that issue, but am still having issues with every 8th node of data being skipped

Comment: Edited the code. Will post an elegant solution soon

Comment: Now everything is working except that the last row of data is not there and is instead a copy of the 1st row. so after the 29th row, row 30 is displaying the data for golden state instead of new york.

Comment: edited the code. please see. if it helps, please mark it as answer.